# Dynamically Add Fields to Django Models & Migrate & Return on Template

Tags: python, django

I want superuser or agent to be able to add fields to user profile on the go during collection of data from users.

For example, the agent will click add new field button via frontend, and the link will automatically create the field, add to the 'Profile' model and makemigrations via django South. Now I tried doing this via inlineformset factory adding additional fields.

The problem is the fields are not being created in the database so saving data inputted in the fields are not working too.

I have 'Profile'model for user details and 'Userform' for details related to User model.

So now below is my forms and views

```
class BaseProfileEditInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super().add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['more_field'] = forms.CharField()
        form.fields['more_field'] = forms.CharField()
```

views

```
@login_required
def edit_user_profile(request, pk):
    userpro = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user_form = UserForm(instance=userpro)

    ProfileInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(CustomUser, Profile, exclude=['user','pub_date','modified_date','basic_verification','phone_confirmed'],formset=BaseProfileEditInlineFormSet, max_num=1, can_delete=False)
    formset = ProfileInlineFormset(instance=userpro)

    if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.id == userpro.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=userpro)
            formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=userpro)

            if user_form.is_valid():
                created_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=userpro)

                if formset.is_valid():
                    created_user.save()
                    formset.save()
                    return HttpResponse('saved data')
        return render(request, 'accounts/account_update.html', {'pk':pk, 'user_form': user_form, 'formset':formset,})
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

What am I missing?

Also do you think this is a nice idea based on the fact that migrations in production will be different from the one in local server? Or it's better to define the fields in models instead of adding this feature. I need enlightenment.

Comment: Does not sound like a good idea. Managing objects that dynamically extend themselves, the class they are instances of and views that use them is a recipe for desaster. If I wanted to have sort of dynamic attributes on user profiles, I'd either go for an extra profile field that can store serialized key-value pairs to hold the extended information or use some sort intermediary model that has an FK reference to a profile an then holds a name and a value. For each extended attribute you want to add, you'd create such an object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You rock.